# How to align an image and a text to center in the same row using CSS?

Tags: html, css, header, alignment, center

I'm working on a website and I have a big problem. I can't align to the center an image and a text in the same row.

My HTML code:

```css
.title2 {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal bold 76px/87px Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #4a4949;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="img.png" width="200" height="150" >
  <h1 class="title2">Website</h1> 
</div>
```

Now they are in the same line, but not in the middle. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Add `justify-content: center;` in `header`

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: center;` on `.header`

```css
.title2 {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal bold 76px/87px Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #4a4949;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <img src="img.png" width="200" height="150" >
      <h1 class="title2">Website</h1> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `margin: auto;` for the `.header` div? This will require you to set a `width` though. And for the contents, add a `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS file, add this to the `.header`.
`justify-content: center;`
This will solve your problem.